# Spring security: Cannot call sendRedirect() after the response has been committed

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-security

I'm using the following code for logout:

```
public class LogoutHandler extends SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler {


@Override
public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    if(!response.isCommitted()) {
        String targetURL = "myUrl";
        response.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE);
        response.getWriter().write(target);
        response.getWriter().flush();
        response.getWriter().close();
        getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, targetURL);
    }

 }

}
```

But when calling /logout WS I got the following exception:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendRedirect() after the response has been committed
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:494)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:138)
at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.FirewalledResponse.sendRedirect(FirewalledResponse.java:26)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:138)
```

Comment: you simply can't do a `sendRedirect` after you have flushed the response

Comment: how can we correct my code?

Comment: But then how are we supposed to use `onLogoutSuccess`? Without a redirect?

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't use `sendRedirect` after you have written a body because then the response is "committed".

If you want a redirect with custom body, you can set the equivalent of doing a redirect *before* writing the response body:

```java
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);
response.setHeader("Location", targetURL);
```

Comment: Now I don't have the exception but I don't redirect to target page.

Comment: I using embedded Tomcat Spring application. This setHeader work, but no sure why setError then sendRedirect will raise exception, but run in standalone tomcat don't raise exception...

Comment: But then how are we supposed to use `onLogoutSuccess`? Without a redirect?